# Issue with apexcharts resizing in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, apexcharts

I am a learning front-end coder, originally a data analyst, trying to fit an ApexChart visual into a flexbox element. At 2560x1440 pixels, it looks good. However, when I resize it further, the height becomes too small to read, though the width remains fine. I think I have made a simple mistake in the HTML or styling, but I'm unable to find it. I have attached my `App.js` and `App.css` files for your reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script defer src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
        <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div>
            <header id="header">
                <h1>innovation platform portal</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="flex1">
                    <div class="block block1">
                        <div class="block-inner">
                            <p class="text-primary">TOTAL ASSETS</p>
                            <span class="material-icons-outlined text-sf">inventory_2</span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">
                            <div id="number_of_assets">
                                6
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block block2">
                        <div class="block-inner">
                            <p class="text-primary">DATA CONNECTIONS</p>
                            <span class="material-icons-outlined text-sf">handshake</span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-primary font-weight-bold">
                            <div id="number_of_connections" class="text-primary font-weight-bold">
                                12
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block block3">
                        <Chart
                            options={this.state.options}
                            series={this.state.series}
                            type="bar"
                            width="100%"
                            height="100%"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block block3">
                    <Chart
                        options={this.state.options}
                        series={this.state.series}
                        type="bar"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Here is my `App.css`:

```css
html,body
{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.text-sf {
color:#e22925;
}

.text-primary {
color:#666666;
}   

.font-weight-bold {
font-weight:600;
}

#header {
display:flex;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
height:7vh;
background-color:#e22925;
color:#ffffff;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
font-size:2vh;
font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;
text-transform:capitalize;
}

/*image in the header*/
img {
position:absolute;
display:flex;
left:2.5vw;
padding:35px 0;
max-width:10%;
}

/*sets up the flex container directly below the header*/
.container {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:30vh;
border-bottom:solid 1px;
border-color:#d2d2d3;
}


/*controls settings of all the boxes in the flex*/
.block {
min-height:100%;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
margin:.125vw;
}

/*this is the size of text below "total assets"*/
.block > span {
font-size:5vh;
font-weight:600;
margin-left:20%;
padding:2px;
}

/*seperate "total assets" from the box icon*/
.block-inner {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

/*size of the header in two left boxes*/
.block-inner > p {
font-size: 2.5vh;
}

/*size of the images in the first 2 boxes*/
.block-inner > span {
font-size: 3vw;
}

/*total assets*/
.block1 {
height:90%;
flex:0 0 calc(20%);
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-around;
background-color:#ffffff;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}


/*data connections*/
.block2 {        
height:90%;
flex:0 0 calc(20vw);
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-around;
background-color:#ffffff;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}

/*assets shared by account*/
.block3 {
width:29%;
height:100%;
flex:0 0 calc(29%);
background-color:#ffffff;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
padding:1px;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}

/*top consumed assets*/
.block4 {
width:29%;
height:100%;
flex:0 0 calc(29%);
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding: 1px;
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}


/*sets the options of the flex element containing the boxes*/
#flex1  {
display:flex;
height:95%;
width:100%;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

.container,.flex1 {
flex-direction:column;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex:10%;
display:flex;
}   

}

@media screen and (min-height: 600px) {

.container, .flex1 {
flex-direction:row;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex:10%;
display:flex;
}

}
```

Can you help me determine what's causing my problem? Also, could you please help me figure out how to add more than one visual to `App.js`? I tried using:

```
function App {
class Bar extends App {

    constructor(props) {
```

But the screen comes back as just plain blank

Here is my App.css
html,body
{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.text-sf {
color:#e22925;
}

.text-primary {
color:#666666;
}   

.font-weight-bold {
font-weight:600;
}

#header {
display:flex;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
height:7vh;
background-color:#e22925;
color:#ffffff;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
font-size:2vh;
font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;
text-transform:capitalize;
}

/*image in the header*/
img {
position:absolute;
display:flex;
left:2.5vw;
padding:35px 0;
max-width:10%;
}

/*sets up the flex container directly below the header*/
.container {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
height:30vh;
border-bottom:solid 1px;
border-color:#d2d2d3;
}


/*controls settings of all the boxes in the flex*/
.block {
min-height:100%;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
margin:.125vw;
}

/*this is the size of text below "total assets"*/
.block > span {
font-size:5vh;
font-weight:600;
margin-left:20%;
padding:2px;
}

/*seperate "total assets" from the box icon*/
.block-inner {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

/*size of the header in two left boxes*/
.block-inner > p {
font-size: 2.5vh;
}

/*size of the images in the first 2 boxes*/
.block-inner > span {
font-size: 3vw;
}

/*total assets*/
.block1 {
height:90%;
flex:0 0 calc(20%);
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-around;
background-color:#ffffff;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}


/*data connections*/
.block2 {        
height:90%;
flex:0 0 calc(20vw);
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-around;
background-color:#ffffff;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}

/*assets shared by account*/
.block3 {
width:29%;
height:100%;
flex:0 0 calc(29%);
background-color:#ffffff;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
padding:1px;
box-sizing:border-box;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}

/*top consumed assets*/
.block4 {
width:29%;
height:100%;
flex:0 0 calc(29%);
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding: 1px;
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
border:1px solid #d2d2d3;
border-radius:5px;
}


/*sets the options of the flex element containing the boxes*/
#flex1  {
display:flex;
height:95%;
width:100%;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

.container,.flex1 {
flex-direction:column;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex:10%;
display:flex;
}   

}

@media screen and (min-height: 600px) {

.container, .flex1 {
flex-direction:row;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex:10%;
display:flex;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

so the issue was setting the height of the container that the chart was in to anything below 30vh. If I just let the chart take 100% of the container, it works perfectly, and that height equates to 30vh.